# Issues related to checkPointPageBufferSize and WalAutoArchiveAfterInactivity in Ignite

Tags: ignite

I have set `checkPointPageBufferSize` to 0. It is said that if 0 is mentioned then it calculates automatically. When I saw the logs it prints 0 so what is value of `checkPointPageBufferSize` which is calculated automatically. I am using Ignite 2.9.0.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I've answered the part about `checkPointPageBufferSize`. You should split the question into two separate questions in order to have them both answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly use 0 as the `checkPointPageBufferSize` or just leave as is then it will be defaulted to a value which is function of the data region size.

- less than `1GB` - min (`256MB`, Data_Region_Size)
- between `1GB` and `8GB` - Data_Region_Size / 4
- more than `8GB` - `2GB`

More details could be found in the [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.9.0/perf-and-troubleshooting/persistence-tuning#adjusting-checkpointing-buffer-size).

Comment: Why log is printing 0 for checkpointpagebuffer size

Comment: Is it a message that prints a configuration? The message that shows an actual value looks like "Started page memory". Could you please grep for it? @DipakJadhav